# Multiple duplicate rows created in java table from 1 single row in sql

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database, swing

I created a GUI which links to a database and retrieves the values and displays it in a table using swing. But for some reason the table shows multiple duplicate rows for each row in sql table. What's wrong? This is the code block which retrieves data from database.This is how the GUI table looks.
This is the database table.

[image]

```
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/nic?useSSL=false", "student" , "student");
PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("select * from companies, plants where plants.company_id=?");
ps.setString(1,id);
ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();
if(rs.next())
    jLabel1.setText(rs.getString("company_name_l"));
rs.previous();
while(rs.next()){
    DefaultTableModel model=(DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
    String row[]={rs.getString("plant_id"),rs.getString("plant_name_l"),rs.getString("plant_name_s")};
    model.addRow(row);
}
```

Comment: I guess you are trying to access two tables at once. In this case, you can join them based on `company_id` like `select * from companies INNER JOIN plants ON companies.company_id = plants.company_id WHERE  companies.company_id = ?`

Comment: You almost certainly don't have a single row in your result set: your query is generating a cross-join because you don't have any correlation between the two tables.  Explicitly list the join and include an `ON` clause.

Comment: Yes. That's what i realised.

Comment: You are selecting data from two tables. You have not linked the tables in any way, so the database gives you the cartesian product, also referred to as a cross-join, linking every row in one table to every row in the other. So, if you have 5 companies and 10 plants, you get 50 rows returned. To avoid this, link the tables with something like  `select * from companies INNER JOIN plants ON  companies.company_id = plants.company_id where ...`

Comment: i tried inner join method but the table now returned is empty. Do i need to change the code further?

Comment: Nevermind. It worked fine. Thanks